How do I undo these screws holding in the base of the backseat? [2006 Fiesta Style]
I need to take out the base of the backseats in this 2006 Ford Fiesta Style (please see the collection of images shown in the first attached JPG for the vehicle's details). There are two bolts or screws which I haven't had cause to work with before holding it in—they are both like that seen in the collection of images shown in the second attached JPG (the collection of images with the orange background). I measured the 'socket' of the bolt to be 8mm, as the third attached JPG shows. I believe they're called "Socket Button Screws" and need either an Allen Wrench to undo or else a Ratchet with a Hex Bit.
Could someone please confirm which is the right tool to undo these screws.
The pink boxes in the collection of images with the orange background just mark the locations of these screws that I need to target.




Looks like Torx. Buy a set and find one that fits snugly, or ask a dealer for exact dimension. My guess would be around T40-T55-range.

I was able to do it today with a Draper ratchet that I was able to borrow using a hexagonal bit—though not Torx-type—that had "cr mv 40" marked on it. So I guess a regular hexagonal Allen Key would also work. But maybe doing so repeatedly would ruin the head of the screw. So I think if I just get a Torx Allen Key that fits then that should be fine, right?

You should absolutely get Torx. Otherwise you'll wreck the screw quickly.
